# How do I hide the content of the site only for Android devices?

Tags: javascript, android, html, .htaccess

Is there any way to hide the site only for android devices?
Maybe there is an option to redirect android users to a separate page?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can firstly check the user agent to distinguish Android devices.

```js
 const userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
```

If is an Android device do the redirect

```
 if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
   window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
 }
```

Wrap all the code in the page load function

```
window.onload = function() {
   const userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
   if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
     window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
   }
};
```